# ArcGis Pro ModelBuilder: display properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1. I would like to export several ModelBuilder layouts for a publication. Models I built myself all look the same: same color for elements like input data/tools/output data, all without outline. Another model I downloaded and modified shows different colors and black outlines. I wanted to change that, but I don't know how. Couldn't find anything like "Display properties". Diagram properties also only let me format the font. I guess it must be possible, otherwise I wonder how the downloaded model was modified.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found any display properties, but when I saved the modified model, it was automatically put into the same layout (no outline, same color) as the selfmade models. With the notice, that the model is saved to a new version. Seems like ArcGIS Pro 3.0 only allows one style.